# Indexing for query using CASE for join

Tags: oracle, index, optimization, oracle-10g

I'm trying to optimize a query on Oracle 10g (I know!), and I have a 4 column table which contains varchar2 values similar to this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Settings (
    Client VARCAR2(50)
    , Class VARCHAR2(50)
    , Setting VARCHAR2(50)
    , Setting_Value VARCHAR(20)
)
```

The query is meant to use static values for Client and Class, these have been hardcoded, while Setting varies in two sections, and Setting_Value should join to different columns in another table, depending on the value of Setting.

I've been setting up the join using this structure:

Edit: It appears there's been confusion. The Setting column effectively points to the column name of the `other_table`. As such, Settings records act as filters for a given Client/Class operation. As such, adding Setting to the `other_table` is counterproductive.

```
WHERE Settings.SettingValue =
    CASE Settings.Setting
        WHEN 'Column1' THEN other_table.Column1
        WHEN 'Column2' THEN other_table.Column2
        WHEN 'Column3' THEN other_table.Column3
        ...
```

The problem is that I can't get Oracle 10g to hit any indexes on other_table for the values in the CASE statement. Is there a strategy I'm missing or a structure that would work for Oracle 10g to use an index as opposed to a full table scan?

Comment: Have you tried `OR`? :`(setting = 'A' and value = column1) or (setting = 'B' and value = column2)`
Or maybe `union all`

Comment: If you can add `Setting` column to `other_table` and copy its value there then you will be able to create a function based index which will be used efficiently.

Comment: Wait, you want the optimiser to guess in advance which indexes it will need based on the outcome of your case statement?

Comment: Can you provide execution plan for this SQL?

Comment: Also try to create function based index on the table .

Comment: @Vercelli, I ended up going with your suggestion. Add an answer with the same info, please.

Comment: @JaazCole Ok, you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try with `OR` like:

```
select * 
  from myTable join otherTable
on (setting = 'A' and value = column1) or 
   (setting = 'B' and value = column2)
```

Also `UNION ALL` may work for you

```
select * from myTable join otherTable on setting = 'A' and value = column1
union all
select * from myTable join otherTable on setting = 'B' and value = column2
```